# How to set tab height to content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have incorporated a JQuery tab into my website, however I want my tabs to expand and contract the height to the content inside. For instance at the moment my first tab expands to the height of the content inside, when I go to the second tab it stays at the height of the first tab, even though it has much less content. Sorry if this is confusing.

Here is the code for the tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

//Default Action
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});

  });
  </script>
```

And here is a piece of code I use to control the height of the `div` with the surrounding `div` wrapper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var height = $("#content").height();
$(".tab_container").height(height);
});
</script>
```

If you need any more info let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: Do you currently have anything calling that, or is that only executed on page load?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that initially it works correctly because you have the code on page load, but once the content changes height, you don't have anything that recalls that function. I would wrap that function around a

```
 $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
      var contentHeight = $("#content").height();
      $(".tab_container").height(contentHeight);
 });
```

Comment: Hi, your code works in terms of it refreshing the height, however it sets the height of the other div to the content height, how could i change it to a min-height. Before i added this code, even if i had no content in the first tab the tab still had a min height. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can always say something like if contentHeight < 500 than contentHeight = 500, that way your min height will be 500px.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the wrapper div would expand and contract according to the height of the content. Are you sure the height is not being set somewhere? A link to an example in JSFiddle would be helpful.